# How to Right Pad a Hexadecimal in C

Tags: c

So I know (after a lot of confusing google searching) that to right pad a string, one would use fprintf("%-10s", string), or something like that to pad with spaces up to 10 length.

So I have two questions:

I know that left-pad is similar, but what would the syntax for it be? (I'm sorry, I did google, but got confused by conflicting answers...)

And more importantly, how would I right-pad a hexidecimal? Say I have an int i want to convert to hex with %02X. Could I still use %-1002X ? Wouldn't that screw it up?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply try this?

Comment: I'm not finished coding yet, so it wouldn't compile. I figured it wouldn't work - it seems obvious that it wouldn't, just by looking at the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` conversion formats allow you to either left-pad or right-pad the conversion result, but not both at the same time. Right-padding an integer conversion is the same as right padding anything else - just specify the negative field width, like `%-10x`. You cannot both left-pad and right-pad at the same time: you can only specify only one *width* in the format. Your original `%02x` is already explicitly using left padding. You cannot add right-padding on top of that.

However, it looks like the purpose of your `%02x` is to produce zero-padded output that has at least 2 digits. This can be achieved through using *precision* component of the format instead of using *width*. Format like `%.2x` will also successfully produce 2 digit hex conversion.

By using precision instead of width, you leave width available for padding purposes. E.g. format like `%-10.2x` will produce 2-digit conversions (padded with zeros) that are right padded with spaces to 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
printf("Hex %8.8x", someInt);
```

Or use `fprintf()`, `sprintf()`, `snprintf()`, whatever... If you're starting with a hex *string*, use snprintf() with the `%-8s` format specifier to capture the translation into a char * buffer, and then use a for loop or to substitute spaces with '0' characters.

Comment: Thanks! I know I can use a for-loop, but I was kind of hoping to do it in one line...if that's not possible, I will probably use a for-loop.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `scanf()` `sscan()` or with  `"%x"` to convert your hex string to an `int`, and then print it out with `"%8.8x"` as shown above.